# How to restart windows services in vm from my local using java

Tags: java, automation, windows-services, remote-desktop

I am trying to automate the manual process of re starting few services in windows for one of my project. Normally I do mstsc to the windows box and then I will re start the services I want.

Is there any library in java that I can connect to a remote machine and restart the services programmatically.

If in local, commands like `net stop [service name] && net start [service name]` were working fine. But, not sure how to do the same in a remote windows machine from my local.

Any solution in this regard helps. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

NET only works with local services.

Use [SC](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) to control services on a remote machine:

```
SC [\\server] [command] [service_name]
```

Note that your account must have the rights to control the service on the remote machine.

Comment: But, My remote machine is having separate credentials. Seems like there is no parameter where we can key in credentials in sc commands list for remote machine login. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Try RunAs or PsExec: https://serverfault.com/questions/359010/execute-windows-sc-command-as-another-user